# How to I get intellisense (auto suggestion) for an object's inner and outer properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a CSS styles object (in React with Typescript), that is made of other objects of type React.CSSProperties. When I use an interface to declare a key/value object type, i get intellisens for the React.CSSProperties in each object, but i lose the intellisense of the properties of the styles object.

```
interface IStyleMap {
    [key: string]: React.CSSProperties;
}

const styles: IStyleMap = {
    text1: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      textAlign: "center"
    }, // i get intellisense (auto suggestion) for text1,2's css props
    text2: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      textAlign: "left"
    }
} 
styles.text1; // but i don't have intellisense (auto suggestion) for: styles -> text1, text2
```

When I send this object to a generic function, i get back intellisense for the styles object props, but I lose each object's React.CSSProperties intellisense.

```
function asStyleMap<T extends IStyleMap>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

const styles = asStyleMap({
    text1: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      textAlign: "center"
    }, // here the intellisense (auto suggestion) is lost
    text2: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      textAlign: "left"
    }
});

styles.text1; // I get intellisense (auto suggestion) for: styles -> text1, text2
```

How can i get in  intellisense (auto suggestion) to work in styles object and in its inner props as well?

[codesandbox link](http://codesandbox.io/s/z3rqwz259p)

Answer (score 0):

To get completion of CSS properties, the type of the `text1` property of the contextual type of the argument to `asStyleMap` needs to include all the properties of `React.CSSProperties`.  When this contextual type is just `T`, you just get the existing properties of your object literal, which is useless.  The following is working for me:

```
function asStyleMap<T extends IStyleMap>(arg: T & {[K in keyof T]: React.CSSProperties}): T {
    return arg;
}
```

TypeScript still infers `T` based on the type of the argument but then intersects each existing property of `T` with `React.CSSProperties`.

You might think the following should also work, but it doesn't:

```
function asStyleMap<T extends IStyleMap>(arg: T & IStyleMap): T {
    return arg;
}
```

This is because the type of a given property (here `text1`) of an intersection type does not consider index signatures (like the one in `IStyleMap`) if another constituent of the intersection (`T`) has a property of the given name.  Unfortunately, this rule probably can't be changed because the use of an intersection type like `{a: A} & {[n: string]: B}` is a popular hack to get a type with an index signature and some properties that are inconsistent with it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Can you provide a link that shows more examples of this "hack"? Thanks Matt.

Comment: I don't have such a link at hand.  If you have a specific follow-up question about how the technique works or how to solve another scenario, you can post it here and I will look.